# VueJS updated() lifecycle hook causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hook

I have a simple VueJS app. In one of my components, I'm trying to retrieve a list of articles. If the user is logged in, I make a specific request. Otherwise, I make another one. Here's my code :

```js
<script>
  import { getFollowersPosts } from './../services/post';

  export default {
    name: 'Home',
    props: {
      user: Object
    },
    data() {
      return {
        posts: []
      }
    },
    async updated() {
      if (this.user) {
        this.posts = await getFollowersPosts(1);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The thing is, the `user` prop comes from the parent component, and it takes some time before the app retrieves it. Once the `user` is retrieved, it updates the component, then I'm able to make the request to the backend with `getFollowersPosts()` since I now have `user`.

However, once I get the request result, I need to update the `posts` array. This causes the component to update again, and start all over again. Now what I get is the component updating indefinitely, and even worse, the MySQL databases ends up closing the connection.

Is there a way to avoid that ? I just want to retrieve the list of articles, and that's it !

Thanks.

**tl;dr** I'm trying to make a request that updates the component's data after a prop updates, but it causes the component to update infinitely. If I use another lifecycle hook like `created()`, I won't be able to retrieve the `user` prop.

Answer (score 4):

You should rather watch for change on the user object and make the getFollowersPosts() request there.

```
watch: {
    user: function (val) {
      if (val) {
        this.posts = await getFollowersPosts(1);
      }
    }
}
```

You can read more about watchers here: https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Thanks ! In the end I found the solution on my own. I posted the answer for others, and I used the solution you proposed. As I wrote, I was struggling for a couple hours and I found the solution randomly right after asking Stackoverflow.

Comment: Glad you found the solution :) Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Updated hook can be called many times, find a detailed answer at [Vue3 lifecycle hooks with real-time example](https://blog.canopas.com/vue-3-lifecycle-hooks-with-real-time-example-1b772b89e085)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I've been struggling for hours to find an answer, and right after posting my question I ended up finding the solution.

So I got it to work using a watcher. I guess the watcher is called only once for each prop that's updated. Here's my code now :

```js
<script>
  import { getFollowersPosts } from './../services/post';

  export default {
    name: 'Home',
    props: {
      user: Object
    },
    data() {
      return {
        posts: []
      }
    },
    watch: {
      user: async function() {
        if (this.user) {
          this.posts = await getFollowersPosts(1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```